# 3.5 inch DPI display setup on Android things. How to?

Tags: display, android-things

Hi please help with installation display to my Raspberry.
It perfectly work with standard OS but I doesn't understand how to install it to Android.
Display connected via GPIO. 
Does it general possible for this OS?

Comment: Do you have an opportunity to connect it through HDMI?

Comment: @Onik Unfortunately no. This display have only GPIO outputs and perfectly fit inside box

Comment: I'm afraid, you should write your own display driver. To my knowledge, there is no a out-of-the-box solution.